# Facebook API returning ID instead of email

Tags: email, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a game in unity and was using a facebook connect plugin by prime31. Previously I was acquiring the Facebook user's email adress but now when I call that I get the Facebook ID. 
I checked it with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Demail and it returns the Facebook ID.

Has Facebook recently changed something? Can you guys tell me how should I retrieve the email address now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct call - make sure you have the `email` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)  ( A call to `/me/permissions` will verify) and the user actually has an email address listed - it's possible a very small number do not.

Comment: It was working like 2 days back and now i'm getting this.
I'm trying to access my own email address which I know is listed and all the permissions are set